# Bjt q point graph

Tags: voltage, transistors, current, amplifier, bias

Please w[image]hat does this part of the graph represents?

Comment: Transistor Parametric curves Ic versus some ib (fixed current). Explained just to the "left".

Answer (score 1):

It represents how much current will flow from C to E (=Ic) when applying 3 different base currents from B to E (=Ib) and at the same time applying a rather high voltage from C to E (=Vce).

Comment: So does that mean that the highest base current supplied is now Ib3?

Comment: Yes, ib3 is the highest base current which produces the highest collector current ic3.